# Selecting all nodes containing text with XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have been struggling to resolve this problem I am having over the past couple of days. Say, I want to get all the text() from a HTML document, however I only want to know of and retrieve of the XPath of the node that contains text data. Example:

```
 foreach (var textNode in node.SelectNodes(".//text()")) 
 //do stuff here
```

However, when it comes to retrieving the XPath of the textNode using `textNode.XPath`, I get the full XPath including the `#text` node:

`/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/a[1]/#text`

Yet I only want the containing node of the text, for example:

`/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/a[1]`

Could anyone point me toward a better XPath solution to retrieve all nodes that contains text but only retrieve the XPath up until the containing node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you

```
string[] elements = getXPath(textNode).Split(new char[1] { '/' });
return String.Join("/", elements, 0, elements.Length-2);
```

Comment: I have thought about splitting up the XPath and then removing the #text node. This could possibly be the best solution yet, but I still want to see if this problem can be resolved by just using XPath. Will mark this answer as answered if I still haven't figured a solution out using XPath by the end of today.

Comment: I use the 1st line, but it gives error that getXPath can't be found. Which namespace contain  getXPath?

Comment: @user585440 sorry not sure I remember how this function works, but it looks that it depends on your environment. It seems to return String object containing given `textNode` with contents. I believe you can find similar functions in official .NET docs.

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of**:

```
.//text()
```

**use**:

```
.//*[normalize-space(text())]
```

This selects all "leaf-elements"-descendants of the context (current) node that have at least one non-whitespace-only text node child.

Comment: Whilst that XPath does work as expected (returning the continuing text node), I am still getting some oddities.

For example:

Say this is the node we want to retrieve all of the text data from:

`<div><span>This is a<a href="#">test</a>link</span></div>`

Using `.//text()` will return

`This is a`

 | `test`

 | `link`

Whilst `.//*[normalize-space(text())]` is returning:

`This is a test link`

 | `This is a`

 | `test`

 | `link`

Comment: @DanielClark, XPath expressions do not "return" -- they "select". The expression you see "oddities" about doesn't select any text node at all -- it selects the parents (elements) of the text nodes. You then *must* get each individual text-node child of any such element. What you are doing instead (and this is the reason for the "oddities") is getting the string value of the parent -- this is the concatenation of all of its text node descendants.

Comment: Ah right my mistake, you're correct. Either way, I have managed to scrap the text data by combining the suggested expression posted by you and then splitting the resulting data as suggested by @ilya-khaustov